# Content turns white-ish when opening materialize Modal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, materialize

I have been trying to make a login modal in React using the Materialize library and have been coming across this weird problem. The input fields aren't displaying correctly, and the checkbox isn't even appearing. Also, the title card seems to be white. I've been trying to follow this codepen: https://codepen.io/skcals/pen/bxdpaN.

Here's the component where I open and display the Modal:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css";
import { NavItem } from "react-materialize";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


import "./style.css";

export default class LoginModal extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    const modal = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

    let elems = modal.querySelector('.modal');
    M.Modal.init(elems, {
      'dismissible' : true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavItem>
        <div className="container center">
          <a href="#login" className="modal-trigger">Login</a>
        </div>

        <div id="login" className="modal ">
          <h5 className="modal-close">&#10005;</h5>
          <div className="modal-content center">
            <h4>Login Form</h4>
            <br/>

            <form action="#">

              <div className="input-field">
                <i className="material-icons prefix">person</i>
                <input type="text" id="name"/>
                <label for="name">Username</label>
              </div>
              <br/>

              <div className="input-field">
                <i className="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
                <input type="password" id="pass"/>
                <label for="pass">Password</label>
              </div>
              <br/>

              <div className="left remember-me">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
                <label for="check">Remember Me</label>
              </div>
              <br/>

              <input type="submit" value="Login" classNameName="btn btn-large"/>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </NavItem>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the style.css file

```css
a.btn{
  margin-top: 30%;
}
.modal{
 max-height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}

input[type="submit"]{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.modal-close{
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.remember-me {
  margin-left: 2vh;
}
```

[Here's the modal once it is opened:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7hf9.png)

As you can see, everything is white/white-ish and not appearing correctly. If anyone has any idea why this is happening, I would really like to know.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In the CodePen you linked, there are other styles and JS that is being loaded on the page. You can see them by clicking on `Settings` and then looking at the `CSS` and `JavaScript` tabs. You'll need to include those three resources (one CSS, two JS) somewhere in your app as well.

Comment: I did include two of them(the materialize js script and materialize css file) in the public/index.html file. I did not include jquery on purpose, because I'm not using any jquery in my code.